# How can Socket.close() fail (no exception is thrown)?

Tags: java, sockets

In a multithreaded application, I have one thread which reads data from a socket connection until a reading timeout occurs. It then sets a closing flag, sends itself an interrupt signal and does some cleanup before exiting. As part of that cleanup, it calls `close()` on the client socket.

I verified in a debugger that the call to `close()` actually happens. Also, it does not throw an exception. Still, the socket reports being connected. I know, because there is another thread `wait`ing for it to become disconnected. This thread should later reconnect it, but doesn't because calling `isConnected()` keeps returning `true`.

This causes a situation in which neither data is read, nor the socket is being cleaned up and reconnected again.

If calling `Socket.close()`, is there any way this can silently fail?

Comment: When you close a socket it has to be closed on both ends to be removed completely. Are you calling close() on both ends?

Comment: You can't reconnect a socket once it's been closed; from the javadoc of `Socket.close()` :` Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or
> rebound). A new socket needs to be created.`

Comment: @Peter - the other end is an industrial black-box device, I have no idea what happens inside that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isConnected` does not mean *"is connected to server"* but *"has once been connected"*. Use `isClosed` if you want to know if the socket has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

`isConnected()` does not mean what you think. I will always remain true after you have connected if I remember it correctly.

Edit: From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29):

`true if the socket successfuly connected to a server`

That means that it won't become false when you get disconnected.

Edit2: I saw that some other answers recommend that you should check `isClosed`. Note that `isClosed` only returns true if you have invoked `close()`. It won't automatically start returning true if the other side closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Combining artbristol's comment, Kaj's and dawce's answers and some additional diagnostics I did, the full answer is:

1. `close()` probably did *not* fail. You can't check the socket's current connection state with `isConnected()`, this only tells you if there ever has been a successful connection. Calling `isClosed()` will tell you if `close()` has been called on your side before.
2. In debugging, a packet sniffer could show you what really happens on the wire as you step through the code. For your example, this should show that the connection is indeed being closed on the network layer, i. e., you should see FIN and corresponding ACK packets and then no more.
3. If you have determined that the socket was closed, you can't reconnect or rebind it. Rather, you have to create a new socket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such behaviour. Perhaps the second thread would have more luck calling `isClosed`?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody came here and wondering how to check if a `Socket` is closed.

```
socket.isConnected() && socket.isClosed()
```

Comment: to avoid future frustration, `socket.isConnected()` does not return whether the socket is currently connected or not, but rather, returns `true` if "..if the socket was successfuly connected to a server"; to elaborate further, it will return true if the socket ever connected at any time, even if it is currently not connected.